# Update data in div correctly AJAX (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, ajax

I have div where I display data on page load via AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    email_update();
});

function email_update() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("EmailsList", "Questions")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            var email = result;
            // console.log(result[0].Name);
            for (var i = 0; i <= email.length - 1; i++) {
                var emailHTML = '<div style="margin-left: 25px; margin-top: 10px;>' +
                    '<b style="margin-left: 10px;">' +(i + 1) +
                    '<b style="margin-left:20px;">' + result[i].Email + '</b>'+
                    '<b>' +
                    '<b style="margin-left: 20px;">' +
                    result[i].Name +
                    '</b>' +
                    '</div>';
                $(".email_list").append(emailHTML);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And I have modal window where I enter data and when I click `create` button I need to update this div with new data. Now I do it with code like above. But it duplicate data. I need to delete old and fill with new. Or update.

How I can do this?

Comment: Put $(".email_list").empty() before your while

Comment: Thank's dude!@Webbanditten

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the problem, but I think you need to move his outside of your for loop.

```
$(".email_list").append(emailHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below code I'll work. it will delete your old detail of Div. 
Please let me know if any difficulty.

```
 function email_update() {
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("EmailsList", "Questions")',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    success: function (result) {
  var emailHTML = "";
        $(".email_list").text = "";

        var email = result;
        // console.log(result[0].Name);
        for (var i = 0; i <= email.length - 1; i++) {
          emailHTML   = '<div style="margin-left: 25px; margin-top: 10px;>' +
                '<b style="margin-left: 10px;">' +(i + 1) +
                '<b style="margin-left:20px;">' + result[i].Email + '</b>'+
                '<b>' +
                '<b style="margin-left: 20px;">' +
                result[i].Name +
                '</b>' +
                '</div>';
            $(".email_list").append(emailHTML);
        }
    }
});
```

}